# fprintf modifying string unexpectedly

Tags: c, printf

I'm having problems with sprintf. It appears to be modifying other sections of my code. I'm reading tokens from a file with a .j extension. But before doing that, I create labels in the file using the pathname.j file name by stripping the .j extension from the file:

j_file is pathname.j:

```
//Initialize length of j_file pathname
    j_file_len = strlen(j_file);

    //Initialize
    char if_label[j_file_len];
    char else_label[j_file_len];
    char endif_label[j_file_len];
```

Here I strip the .j extension from the original pathname and add it to three separate variables such that the new file extension is just pathname

```
for (i = 0; i < j_file_len - 2; i++)
        {
            if_label[i] = j_file[i];
            else_label[i] = j_file[i];
            endif_label[i] = j_file[i];
        }

        //Place null terminator
        if_label[j_file_len - 2] = '\0';
        else_label[j_file_len - 2] = '\0';
        endif_label[j_file_len - 2] = '\0';

        //Length of concatenated string
        len_concat = strlen(if_label);
```

Here I search for "if" tokens in my file, I then concatenate a string to the end of `if_label`, and fprint to a file.

```
    //If token is if
    else if (strcmp(tail->token, "if") == 0)
    {
        printf("There are %d IFS\n",if_count );

        printf("IF FOUND\n");

        sprintf(if_count_string, "_IF_%d", if_count);

        strcat(if_label, if_count_string);

        printf("If CONCAT is  %s \n",if_label );


        //Else will match to IF
        else_count = if_count;

        //Create ELSE label for branching

        sprintf(else_count_string, "_ELSE_%d", else_count);

        strcat(else_label, else_count_string);

        printf("Else CONCAT is %s \n",else_label );

        ////

        ///**** EDIT
        //Open file
        FILE *ASM = fopen(asm_file, "a");

        //Perform operation
        fprintf(ASM, "\t; === %s ===\n", tail->token);

        //Create IF label
        fprintf(ASM, "%s\n",if_label);

        //Copy element at top of stack to register
        fprintf(ASM, "\tLDR R0, R6, #0\n");

        //Clear element from stack
        fprintf(ASM, "\tCONST R2, #0\n");
        fprintf(ASM, "\tHICONST R2, #0\n");
        fprintf(ASM, "\tSTR R2, R6, #0\n");

        //Increment stack pointer to point to next element on stack
        fprintf(ASM, "\tADD R6, R6, #1\n");

        //Compare elements element to 0 (element - 0)
        fprintf(ASM, "\tCMPI R0 #0\n");


        //If operation false (= 0) Branch to corresponding else label
        fprintf(ASM, "\tBRz %s\n", else_label);

        //****/

        //Close file
        fclose(ASM);

        //Remove IF label identifier
        for (i = len_concat; if_label[i] != '\0'; i++)
        {
            if_label[i] = '\0';

        }

        len = strlen(if_label);

        printf("new length of if label is %d\n", len);
        printf("Trimmed IF IS %s\n",if_label );

        //Remove ELSE label identifier
         for (i = len_concat; else_label[i] != '\0'; i++)
         {
            else_label[i] = '\0';

         }

        len = strlen(else_label);
        printf("new length of else label is %d\n", len);
        printf("Trimmed ELSE IS %s\n",else_label );

        //Increment if counter
        if_count++;

    }
```

The output I expect is that after each iteration of the for loop towards the end of the code, trimmed IF and trimmed ELSe should just print `pathname`:

```
If CONCAT is  pathname_IF_0
Else CONCAT is pathname_ELSE_0
new length of if label is 8
Trimmed IF IS pathname 
new length of else label is 8 
Trimmed ELSE IS pathname
```

but instead my IF statement is mysteriously being modified by some agent unbeknownst to me. Observe representative output:

```
If CONCAT is  pathname_IF_0 //CORRECT
Else CONCAT is pathname_ELSE_0 //CORRECT
new length of if label is 1//NOT CORRECT
Trimmed IF IS 0 //WHY?!?!?!?
new length of else label is 8 //CORRECT
Trimmed ELSE IS pathname
```

Since this if block occurs in a loop, it messes up subsequent iterations of my code. Why is this happening? I've beat my head over this to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: count variables and string variables are initialized outside of the if bock

```
int if_count = 0;
int else_count = 0;

char if_count_string[100];
char else_count_string[100];
```

Comment: You are missing to show us the important declarations of the buffers where sprintf writes its data, `if_count_string` etc.

Comment: Please also provide the examples of what is to be *correct* output alongside the actual. It is likely you are having pointer problems and full debugging of this requires as much information as possible to paint this predicament.

Comment: @Jens I've added the important declarations that should clarify the code

Comment: have you tried running it through valgrind?

Comment: @Andreas There are no segmentation fault issues, so I'm not sure how valgrind would help? As far as memory leaks are concerned, I'm not making any calls to malloc except in my linked list implementation, which I'm using to store the tokens parsed from the text file, but I doubt that is causing this issue here.

Comment: " There are no segmentation fault issues" --> Hmmmm.  `strcat(if_label, if_count_string);` attempts to  write outside `if_label[]` --> UB.

Comment: @chux, I changed `char if_label[j_file_len];` and `char else_label[j_file_len]` to `char if_label[j_file_len+10];` and `char else_label[j_file_len+10]` but still get the same issue.

Comment: Please post a  [mcve].

Comment: As it currently stands there is more to your code than what is posted. Can you please print the full if-else structure of the 3rd code block along with the loop that its nested in? Also can you pass sample input such that we can verify nothing with your inputs is causing your code to fail? I've been looking at this problem for a few hours now, and I am drawing a blank as well, and can't move forward without more information to this. A valgrind run wouldn't hurt as well.